# How to display a value in the next div html when clicking the previous div in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have many similar `div` containing the same structure containing a `button` shown below :

```
<div>
    <button>Select Equipment</button>
    <span>0</span>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Select Equipment</button>
    <span>0</span>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Select Equipment</button>
    <span>0</span>
</div>
```

When I click the `button` in the first div I want to display the value `1` in the `span` tag of the second `div`. Then when I click the select equipment in the second `div`, it should display a value of `2` in the `span` tag of the third `div`. Can anyone suggest a solution how to do this?

Comment: What about the `<span>` for first `div`?

Comment: I have used .next() in jquery but it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the `index` of the clicked `button` in the set of buttons, than look for a `span` with `eq` like button index + 1 and add to the `span` the text you want.

*** html ***

```
<div>
<button>Select Equipment 1</button>
<span>0</span>
</div>

<div>
<button>Select Equipment 2</button> 
<span>0</span>
</div>

<div>
<button>Select Equipment 3</button> 
<span>0</span>
</div>
```

*** css ***

```
span {
  display: visible;
}
```

*** js ***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery(document).on('click.button','button',function(e){
    var eq = $(this).index('button');
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if($('span').eq(eq+1).length) { $('span').eq(eq+1).show().text(eq+1); }
  });

});
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnL45r2n/1/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parents` to get parent div and use `next` and `find`  to get next `div` and `span` and use `parseInt` for calculation .

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/xnL45r2n/2/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  var rVal = $(this).next('span').text();
  $(this).parents().next().find('span').text(parseInt(rVal) + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this script below your html code.

Please find your updated code:

```
<div>
    <button>Select Equipment</button>
    <span>0</span>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Select Equipment</button>
    <span>0</span>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Select Equipment</button>
    <span>0</span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div button').click(function() {
        var val = $(this).parent().index()+1;
        $(this).parent().next('div').find('span').html(val);
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope, this may be helpful to you.